# Como acessar Web API publicada no IIS externamente

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api

Desenvolvi uma ASP .NET Web Application (API) no Visual Studio 2015 e publiquei no IIS 6.1 para acessar localmente.
Agora eu preciso disponibilizar minha maquina como servidor para acesso externo.
Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 4):

Uma resposta completa depende de como seu ambiente está estruturado, e não é trivial. Vou listar os requisitos de maneira superficial; você precisa resolver os detalhes.

Estou assumindo:

- Uma conexão residencial típica (endereço IP não permanente);
- Um roteador não comercial [como este](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/wndr3700.aspx);
- Um computador com IIS servindo sua WebAPI.

Os passos necessários seriam:

- Configurar seu roteador para permitir que conexões externas sejam roteadas para o computador com IIS;

  - Determine o IP local da sua máquina, ou seu *MAC Address*;
  - Configure no seu *router* a função de *port forwarding*, indicando que toda conexão de origem externa às portas 80 (HTTP) e 443 (HTTPS) sejam roteadas para seu servidor (via IP ou *MAC Address*);
- Configure um serviço de DNS dinâmico para que sua máquina tenha um 'nome' na internet - caso contrário usuários só poderão acessar seu serviço se eles souberem seu IP (que, sendo dinâmico, será periodicamente alterado). Algumas opções:

  - http://www.dynu.com
  - http://www.dnsdynamic.org/
  - http://www.noip.com/

Isso lhe permitirá oferecer sua WebAPI para a internet em geral. Entretanto vários outros pontos devem ser considerados:

- Você está abrindo sua máquina para a internet, e é um alvo potencial para usuários maliciosos;
- A quantidade de usuários que você pode servir é limitada pela sua velocidade/quota de *upload* - que é geralmente bastante baixa em contratos não-comerciais;
- Provedores de acesso no Brasil geralmente não gostam de usuários oferecendo serviços diretamente, portanto verifique se seu contrato com seu provedor de acesso permite este tipo de *setup*.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta bem completa, vou dar uma estudada, caso consiga resolver eu marco como resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Então, acabei achando um Post no site do **dotnetmentors.com**, onde o autor acaba dando varias esplicações de como hospedar ASP.NET Web API no IIS usando o Visual Studio sendo um dos metodo presente no proprio programa.

Lá o autor cita dois tipos de Hospedagem: **Auto Hospedado, IIS hospedagem**

IIS hospedagem(que é o metodo que você deseja), esta bem detalhado como mostra a sitação abaixo:

> Hospedar CustomerApp no ​​IIS
>   gerente de IIS aberto clicando Windows Iniciar -> Executar -> digite inetmgr -> clique em OK
>    
>    Se o IIS não é instalado no seu computador , clique aqui para instalar.
>    
>    Vá para o gerenciador do IIS e clique direito sobre locais e selecione -> -> Adicionar site .
>    
>    Adicionar um novo web site para o IIS
>    
>    Digite os detalhes, como mostrado na imagem abaixo
>    
>    Inserir o nome do site como CustomerApp
>    Alterar o agrupamento de aplicações para ASP.net V4.0
>    Escolha o caminho físico da pasta que contém ASP.NET Web publicadas API. -> Entrei como C: \ CustomerApp
>    Insira o número da porta em que você deseja hospedar API. I usar a porta -> como 9810.

**Links:**
**[dotnetmentors.com](http://dotnetmentors.com/web-api/host-asp-net-web-api-in-iis-using-visual-studio-publish.aspx)**
**[Google](https://www.google.com.br/?gws_rd=ssl#q=como%20publicar%20uma%20api%20em%20net)**

Comment: Respostas com link são desencorajadas aqui. Tente adicionar contexto do que está sendo dito no link, para que ele seja apenas uma referencia, e não a resposta.

Comment: Continua na mesma, você só adicionou mais links, o que de fato piorou a resposta. -1

Comment: @DiegoF, '-', ainda não entendi

Comment: Visite [answer] e (PRINCIPALMENTE) [**aqui**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/706/28595). Um link deve ser apenas referencia, não conter toda a resposta da pergunta.

Comment: @Daniel essa publicação não mostra como posso acessar de fora da rede local (externamente), que é a minha necessidade, mas valeu pelo esforço.